# How to set the default color cycle for all subplots with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

How can I set a default set of colors for plots made with matplotlib?  I can set a particular color map like this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig=plt.figure(i)
ax=plt.gca()
colormap = plt.get_cmap('jet')
ax.set_color_cycle([colormap(k) for k in np.linspace(0, 1, 10)])
```

but is there some way to set the same set of colors for all plots, including subplots?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971269/how-to-pick-a-new-color-for-each-plotted-line-within-a-figure-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Sure! Either [specify `axes.color_cycle` in your `.matplotlibrc` file](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/customizing.html) or set it at runtime using `matplotlib.rcParams` or `matplotlib.rc`.

As an example of the latter:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

# Set the default color cycle
mpl.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = mpl.cycler(color=["r", "k", "c"]) 

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2)

for i in range(10):
    axes[0].plot(x, i * (x - 10)**2)

for i in range(10):
    axes[1].plot(x, i * np.cos(x))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: For those who want more color:

mpl.rcParams['axes.color_cycle'] = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'black', 'purple', 'pink', 'brown', 'orange', 'teal', 'coral', 'lightblue', 'lime', 'lavender', 'turquoise', 'darkgreen', 'tan', 'salmon', 'gold']

Comment: `axes.color_cycle is not a valid rc parameter`

Comment: @endolith [in version 1.5 and later, the new key is `axes.prop_cycle`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37211181/52074)

Comment: @LudoSchmidt i justed spent like 4 hours messing with color cycles. but your list is better. good job.

Comment: How can I set it back to default without having to restart the kernel? I mean, say I just run `mpl.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = mpl.cycler(color=["r", "k", "c"])` and plot a bunch of plots. Now I want to restore the default matplotlib colors and plot another bunch of plots. How do I do it?

Answer (score 54):

Starting from matplotlib 1.5, mpl.rcParams['axes.color_cycle'] is deprecated. You should use axes.prop_cycle:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = mpl.cycler(color=["r", "#e94cdc", "0.7"])
```

Answer (score 5):

In the version of 2.1.0, the below works for me, using set_prop_cycle and module cycler

```
from cycler import cycler
custom_cycler = (cycler(color=['r','b','m','g']))
ax.set_prop_cycle(custom_cycler)
```

you can add additional line attribute

```
custom_cycler = (cycler(color=['r','b','m','g']) + cycler(lw=[1,1,1,2]))
```

'ax' comes from ax=plt.axes() or any axes generator

Comment: this is a third-party module?

Comment: I don't think that. In my memory, it is enclosed with matplotlib.

Comment: `cycler` is not needed. `ax.set_prop_cycle('color', ['r','b','m','g'])` is enough
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/44807301/3753826