# Prettier default plot colors in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

The default colors used in matplotlib (example here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/pie_demo.html) are kind of plain and ugly. I've also noticed that if you plot more than 5-6 different series in a single plot, matplotlib starts repeating colors.

I've seen some gorgeous graphs coming out of other visualization packages (in other languages, by default) that can have 5-6 different series covered by just one color in different shades. Does anyone have a good color set to use in matplotlib? And a way to make matplotlib use it by default?

Comment: .. the colours in that image look pretty good to me.  You can see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397944/default-color-cycle-with-matplotlib) for how to change the default colour cycle, but I'm not sure whether "does anyone have a good color set" is the sort of thing that we can answer.

Comment: There are 1000 sites on the web that will help you choose a good color scheme, but they won't be specific to graphs.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use [Matplotlib's style sheets](https://matplotlib.org/1.5.3/users/style_sheets.html). It has been ported from the [mpltools library](https://tonysyu.github.io/mpltools/) which has a [style](https://tonysyu.github.io/mpltools/api/mpltools.style.html) module that redefine matplotlib rc parameters.

As an example, see the use of the [ggplot style](https://tonysyu.github.io/mpltools/auto_examples/style/plot_ggplot.html) and [Matplotlib's manual](https://matplotlib.org/1.5.3/users/style_sheets.html).

[image]

Comment: It seems this package is now included in matplotlib: http://matplotlib.org/users/style_sheets.html

Answer (score 50):

The question was asked 2 years ago, and today it's much easier to get better style for your plot. You don't even need external packages for that. As @asmaier mentioned in his comment, mpltools.style functionality has been integrated into Matplotlib 1.4, so you can switch styles with:

```
plt.style.use(style_name)
```

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.style.use('ggplot')

num_lines = 6

ax = plt.subplot(111)

for i in range(num_lines):
    x = np.linspace(0,20,200)
    ax.plot(x,np.sin(x)+i)

plt.show()
```

[image]

You can list all available styles with:

```
print plt.style.available
```

In Matplotlib 1.5 several new styles have been added, including many styles from the Seaborn project:

```
plt.style.use('seaborn-dark-palette')
```

[image]

Comment: A demo of the styles is at https://matplotlib.org/gallery/style_sheets/style_sheets_reference.html and if you're trying a few, you'll want to `plt.style.use('default')` to reset the style before applying a new one, since the styles are composable.

Comment: I get at: ax.set_color_cycle(sns.color_palette("coolwarm_r",num_lines))
 AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_color_cycle'

Comment: `set_color_cycle` has now been deprecated. You should instead use: `ax.set_prop_cycle('color', sns.color_palette("coolwarm_r", num_lines))`

Answer (score 25):

Have a look at [prettyplotlib](http://olgabot.github.io/prettyplotlib/) a library — just pointed out to me recently by friends — that modifies matplotlib to be better aligned with the ideas of [Edward Tufte](http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/), as well as some very carefully studied work by [Cynthia Brewer](http://www.personal.psu.edu/cab38/) on color perception.

Comment: Note that according to the github page, prettyplotlib is no longer maintained, and the maintainer suggest the use of the seaborn (https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html) package which also has support for the prettyplotlib color scheme.

Answer (score 16):

The [Seaborn](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/) package (based on Matplotlib) has nice default graph styles, and I've found that it's a nice way to create an appealing color-cycle.

They have a nice discussion of the colorpalettes here: 
https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/color_palettes.html

The following code demonstrates how you can pick a new color_cycle automatically for a simple line plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns   

num_lines = 6

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.set_color_cycle(sns.color_palette("coolwarm_r",num_lines))

for i in range(num_lines):
    x = np.linspace(0,20,200)
    ax.plot(x,np.sin(x)+i)

plt.show()
```

[image]

If you want to just change the linecolors and not use the other seaborn pre-sets such as the gray background, just import seaborn with

```
import seaborn.apionly as sns
```

Answer (score 4):

You can setup a `.matplotlibrc` file.  A really heavily commented example is [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html).  It looks to me like the option you want to change is `axes.color_cycle`.  I don't have any advice on what to make it for a prettier interface -- That's a little too subjective Stack Overflow ;-) (and I'm happy with the defaults)

Answer (score 2):

For a richer set of colours that can be used with `matplotlib`, check out [palettable](https://jiffyclub.github.io/palettable/), featuring the wonderful [Wes Anderson](https://jiffyclub.github.io/palettable/wesanderson/) palletes.

```
$ pip install palettable
$ python
>>> from palettable.colorbrewer.qualitative import Dark2_7
```

Answer (score 2):

A while ago, I created dufte in [matplotx](https://github.com/nschloe/matplotx), a minimalistic style for matplotlib. Install with

```
pip install matplotx
```

and use with

```
plt.style.use(matplotx.styles.dufte)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [colormap](http://matplotlib.org/api/cm_api.html#module-matplotlib.cm) functionality of matplotlib.

A good example is in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931268/using-colormaps-to-set-color-of-line-in-matplotlib) question.  You can show your colormap options [using this script](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps).

Answer (score 0):

I use `ggplot` style for my works you can see list of other styles in this link [matplotlib.org](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/style_sheets/style_sheets_reference.html)

USAGE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
```