# Python matplotlib: Setting the default colours of the colour cycle

Tags: python, matplotlib, rc

This article [How to set the default color cycle for all subplots with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397944/default-color-cycle-with-matplotlib) teaches us how to use `mpl.rcParams['axes.color_cycle'] = ['r', 'k', 'c']` to change the default colour `'r', 'k', 'c'` cycle to red, black and cyan. However, how can I change the actual hex-triplets which `'r', 'k', 'c'` represent? Say I want `'r'` to represent `#8F00FF` (violet)? Or even better, how can I add colours, such that `'v'` represent the hex-triplet `#8F00FF`? I hope to use them to implement them in `mpl.rcParams['axes.color_cycle']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the colors using hex notation directly in for the color cycle, like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler # for mpl>2.2

mpl.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = cycler(color=['r', '#8F00FF', '#A0F0A0'])

# for mpl < 2.2
#mpl.rcParams['axes.color_cycle'] = ['r', '#8F00FF', '#A0F0A0']

y = np.arange(5)
for i in range(7):
    plt.plot(y + i, linewidth=5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Not working. `axes.color_cycle is not a valid rc parameter`. I used: `from cycler import cycler` and
`mpl.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = cycler(color=['#2EBCE7', '#84EE29', '#FF8177'])`