# Matplotlib set_color_cycle versus set_prop_cycle

Tags: python, matplotlib

One of my favorite things to do in Matplotlib is to set the color-cycle to match some colormap, in order to produce line-plots that have a nice progression of colors across the lines. Like this one:

[image]

Previously, this was one line of code using `set_color_cycle`:

```
ax.set_color_cycle([plt.cm.spectral(i) for i in np.linspace(0, 1, num_lines)])
```

But, recently I see a warning:

```
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
The set_color_cycle attribute was deprecated in version 1.5. 
Use set_prop_cycle instead.
```

Using `set_prop_cycle`, I can achieve the same result, but I need to `import cycler`, and the syntax is less compact:

```
from cycler import cycler
colors = [plt.cm.spectral(i) for i in np.linspace(0, 1, num_lines)]
ax.set_prop_cycle(cycler('color', colors))
```

So, my questions are:

Am I using `set_prop_cycle` correctly? (and in the most efficient way?)

Is there an easier way to set the color-cycle to a colormap? In other words, is there some mythical function like this?

```
ax.set_colorcycle_to_colormap('jet', nlines=30)
```

Here is the code for the complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.subplot(111)
num_lines = 30

colors = [plt.cm.spectral(i) for i in np.linspace(0, 1, num_lines)]

# old way: 
ax.set_color_cycle(colors)

# new way:
from cycler import cycler
ax.set_prop_cycle(cycler('color', colors))

for n in range(num_lines):
    x = np.linspace(0,10,500)
    y = np.sin(x)+n
    ax.plot(x, y, lw=3)

plt.show()
```

Comment: `plt.cm.get_cmap('spectral')` for anyone who gets an error trying to access the `spectral` function.

Comment: 'spectral'.capitalize()

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Because the new property cycler can iterate over other properties than just color (e.g. linestyle) you need to specify the `label`, i.e. the property over which to cycle.

```
ax.set_prop_cycle('color', colors)
```

There is no need to import and create a cycler though; so as I see it the only drawback of the new method it that it makes the call 8 characters longer.

There is no magical method that takes a colormap as input and creates the cycler, but you can also shorten your color list creation by directly supplying the numpy array to the colormap.

```
colors = plt.cm.Spectral(np.linspace(0,1,30))
```

Or in combination

```
ax.set_prop_cycle('color',plt.cm.Spectral(np.linspace(0,1,30)))
```

Comment: Ah, so now I can pretty easily specify a whole combination of different colors, linewidths, linestyles, etc. That does seem like an advantage. And the only price to pay is 8 more characters - I can live with that :). And thanks for the tip about passing the linspace to the colormap. In the end, I think that you saved me a few characters!

Comment: I get this error, sadly: AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.cm' has no attribute 'spectral'
Has matplotlib changed yet again?

Comment: @jhaagsma The `spectral` colormap has been removed. You may use any other [valid colormap](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) instead, e.g. `Spectral` or `nipy_spectral`. I updated the answer.