# AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_color_cycle'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to set colour cycle by the following code:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(20, 8.5))
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.09, hspace=0.09)
axes[0].set_color_cycle(['#00FFFF','#0000FF','#DC143C' , '#A52A2A','#7FFF00','#8A2BE2','#000000','#D2691E',\
                           '#008B8B','#B8860B', '#006400', '#FF8C00','#8B0000','#2F4F4F','#FF1493','#FFD700',\
                           '#00FF00','#BA55D3', '#FF4500', '#800080'])
```

However, it pops up with

> "AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_color_cycle'"

```
import matplotlib as mpl, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print(mpl.__version__)
```

gives the output: 3.1.1
Python Version- 3.7.4

Comment: From the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_color_cycle.html): Deprecated since version 1.5: The set_color_cycle function was deprecated in version 1.5. Use set_prop_cycle instead. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44806598/matplotlib-set-color-cycle-versus-set-prop-cycle) may also be useful.

Comment: Thank you. I have used 

axes[0].set_prop_cycle(color=['#00FFFF','#0000FF','#DC143C' , '#A52A2A','#7FFF00','#8A2BE2','#000000','#D2691E',\
                           '#008B8B','#B8860B', '#006400', '#FF8C00','#8B0000','#2F4F4F','#FF1493','#FFD700',\
                           '#00FF00','#BA55D3', '#FF4500', '#800080'])

that solves the problem.