# Unable to change color of plotted lines on matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Referred to this SO post here: [Matplotlib set_color_cycle versus set_prop_cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44806598/matplotlib-set-color-cycle-versus-set-prop-cycle)

But I was unable to set all 20 lines' colors to be different, picture of the graph here:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from cycler import cycler


df = pd.read_csv(r'data.csv', index_col="Date", parse_dates=True)


df.rolling(window=30).max()[30:].head(20)
ax = df.plot()
ax.set(title='Qingdao Port', ylabel='Monthly Average Prices')
ax.set_prop_cycle('color',plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(0,1,20)))
plt.show()
```

Do help me out here!

Comment: You need to set the cycle _before_ you plot anything

Comment: @DavidG how can i do that? apologies, i'm new to python data analysis in general.

Comment: I personally would create a figure and axes `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`, then do `ax.set_prop_cycle(...)`. You can then pass the ax as an argument to `df.plot(ax=ax)` if you wish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User DavidG has helped me with the issue, for future reference the updated code will be included here:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd  
from cycler import cycler

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_prop_cycle('color',plt.cm.tab20(np.linspace(0,1,20)))

df = pd.read_csv(r'data.csv', index_col="Date", parse_dates=True)


df.rolling(window=30).max()[30:].head(20)
df.plot(ax=ax)
ax.set(title='Qingdao Port', ylabel='Monthly Average Prices')
plt.show()
```