# plot add multiple resultes using same colors

Tags: python-3.x, plot

I have list of tuple of tree elemnets, each row draw 3 lines in different 3 colors.

example data of one row:

```
SIR[0] = [(990, 10, 0), (980, 13, 7), (963, 25, 12), (938, 38, 24), (897, 55, 48), (844, 85, 71), (764, 123, 113), (663, 161, 176), (536, 203, 261), (416, 227, 357), (309, 206, 485), (243, 177, 580), (193, 128, 679), (169, 87, 744), (156, 55, 789), (145, 36, 819), (142, 21, 837), (139, 11, 850), (138, 7, 855), (138, 4, 858), (137, 2, 861), (137, 1, 862), (136, 1, 863), (136, 1, 863), (136, 1, 863), (136, 0, 864), (136, 0, 864), (136, 0, 864), (136, 0, 864), (136, 0, 864)]
```

I would like to display same colors between the rows (red, blue, green)

When I add two rows, it added with 6 different colors:

```
plt.plot(SIR[0])
plt.plot(SIR[1])
```

[image]

Expected result is (assuming I have a lot of rows)

[image]

I'm aware about the color variable in plot function, but it will define only for color instead of 3.

How can I define the 3 colors?

Comment: Hi interesting, perhaps use the `fmt` group to specify the hex color or color code https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the default color cycle for all subplots with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397944/how-to-set-the-default-color-cycle-for-all-subplots-with-matplotlib)