# MatPlotLib 0.99.1.1 rcParams['axes.color_cycle']

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm apparently stuck with this old version of MatPlotLib on my Centos 6.4 machine, and some code that works fine on newer versions is broken.  When I do:

`matplotlib.rcParams['axes.color_cycle'] = ['c','m','r','g','b','k']`
I get:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 621, in __setitem__
See rcParams.keys() for a list of valid parameters.'%key)
KeyError: 'axes.color_cycle is not a valid rc parameter.See rcParams.keys() for a list of valid parameters.'`
```

I've found `lines.color`, but it only seems to take one value(?), though there is a color cycle happening...

Is there an equivalent to `axes.colorcyle` for this old version?

Thanks!

Comment: This has been answered in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39522128/1519341).