# how to change each histograph item color in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, colors

> Korean in pictures is not important. Sorry for showing non-english character
>
> environment : Jupyter notebook

[image: here is python dataFrame, which import csv file.]

For this dataFrame(which read csv files), I want to make bar graph which has specific colors on each item.

so, I make some code like that...

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import font_manager, rc
font_name =font_manager.FontProperties(fname="c:/Windows/Fonts/malgun.ttf").get_name()
rc('font', family=font_name)
from matplotlib import colors as mcolors
colors=dict(mcolors.BASE_COLORS,**mcolors.CSS4_COLORS)

data = pd.read_csv('subway.csv')
subwayPassengerPerLine.plot.bar(color=['tab:blue','tab:green','tab:orange','tab:cyan','tab:purple','tab:brown','tab:green','tab:pink','tab:gold','tab:black','tab:black','tab:black','tab:black','tab:black','tab:black','tab:black','tab:black','tab:black','tab:black','tab:black','tab:black','tab:black','tab:black','tab:black','tab:black'])
```

I want to make like this one [image: hope result]

But My code(upper code) doesn't change color.[image: my result(fail)]

how to change color in bar graph like second image? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, you don't need to use tab:"black" ...etc.

Just using

```
subwayPassengerPerLine.plot.bar(y = 'sum',color=['blue','green','orange','cyan','purple','brown','green','pink','gold','black','black','black','black','black','black','black','black','black','black','black','black','black','black','black','black'])
```

This can also help if you want to automate your plot color.

> [How to pick a new color for each plotted line within a figure in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971269/how-to-pick-a-new-color-for-each-plotted-line-within-a-figure-in-matplotlib)

Doc reference

```
https://python-graph-gallery.com/3-control-color-of-barplots/
```

Edited:
Missed the y = 'sum' field. 
If you want to remove the useless legend, add this line too:

```
subwayPassengerPerLine.get_legend().remove()
```

Comment: After reviewing with tab:color, it should also work. Did you try redrawing your graph?

Comment: yes, I did redrawing graph, and also did reRun whole code. I also upload whole code, but It doesn't work.

Comment: subwayPassengerPerLine.plot.bar(color=['blue','green','orange','cyan',
                                       'purple','brown','green','pink','gold','black',
                                       'black','black','black','black','black','black',
                                       'black','black','black','black','black','black',
                                       'black','black','black'])

Comment: also, I changed gold to green, same result occurred(color doesn't changed)

Comment: My bad, missed a line. I have edited my answer. Please try it again.

Comment: Solved well. Thanks for your help:)