module 'matplotlib.cm' has no attribute 'get_cmap'
I'm currently using matplotlib 3.9.0.
I was able to run it before, so I suspect there might be an issue with my environment. I'm not sure how to resolve it.
Here are the details of the error:
File "C:\Users\Desktop\PyTorch_OpenPose_ori\pytorch_advanced-master\4_pose_estimation\inference.py", line 11, in <module>
    from utils.openpose_net import OpenPoseNet
File "C:\Users\Desktop\PyTorch_OpenPose_ori\pytorch_advanced-master\4_pose_estimation\utils\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .decode_pose import *
File "C:\Users\Desktop\PyTorch_OpenPose_ori\pytorch_advanced-master\4_pose_estimation\utils\decode_pose.py", line 18, in <module>
    cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('hsv')
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.cm' has no attribute 'get_cmap'


Could anyone help me figure out how to solve this issue?
I was trying to load weights and perform inference with OpenPose.

matplotlib.cm.get_cmap(name) has been removed from matplotlib.cm.  Instead, you can use  matplotlib.colormaps[name] or matplotlib.colormaps.get_cmap(name).

See issue 28317 on github and in matplotlib's 3.7 change notes

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76436390/7758804

This error originated from matplotlib version 3.9.0.
Try to install older version which might solve your issue:
pip install matplotlib==3.7.3


Although it might work, downgrading should be avoided in general. Libraries evolve, they get updated and improved. Sometimes some old ways change.  In this case, matplotlib.cm.get_cmap(name) is being removed from matplotlib.cm  Instead, matplotlib.colormaps[name] or matplotlib.colormaps.get_cmap(name) (or plt.get_cmap(name)) can be used.

I made matplotlib.colormaps['hsv'] and it worked.
Thank you very much.

There is nothing generally wrong with downgrading as long as it is done in controlled environments - e.g. Conda, Docker, etc. Frequently, that is your only option if you depend on software that is no longer maintained. But of course, take note of what kind of software you are downgrading and make sure that newer versions do not include security patches etc. For matplotlib, it is a fine solution.
