# How to avoid line color repetition in matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib, plot

I am comparing some algorithmic results using matplotlib.pyplot, however it is very difficult to understand what is going on since several lines have the same exact color. Is there a way to avoid this? I don't think that pyplot has only seven colors, has it?

Comment: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/pyplot_tutorial.html

Comment: I suggest you have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805048/how-to-get-different-lines-for-different-plots-in-a-single-figure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matplotlib has more than seven colors. You can specify your color in many ways (see http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/colors_api.html).

For example, you can specify the color using an html hex string:

```
pyplot.plot(x, y, color='#112233')
```

Answer (score 13):

For **Python 3**, from the solutions above you can use:

```
colormap = plt.cm.nipy_spectral
colors = colormap(np.linspace(0, 1, number_of_plots))
ax.set_prop_cycle('color', colors)
```

or:

```
import seaborn as sns
colors = sns.color_palette('hls', number_of_plots)
ax.set_prop_cycle('color', colors)
```

Answer (score 12):

The best thing if you know how many plots you are going to plot is to define the colormap before:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
number_of_plots=10
colormap = plt.cm.nipy_spectral #I suggest to use nipy_spectral, Set1,Paired
ax1.set_color_cycle([colormap(i) for i in np.linspace(0, 1,number_of_plots)])
for i in range(1,number_of_plots+1):
    ax1.plot(np.array([1,5])*i,label=i)

ax1.legend(loc=2)
```

Using `nipy_spectral`

[image]

Using `Set1`
[image]

Comment: Should we be concerned that `set_color_cycle()` is deprecated in `version 1.5`? `plt` suggests to use `set_prop_cycle()` instead (but I haven't tried yet).

Answer (score 6):

I would also suggest the use of [Seaborn](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/). With this library it is very easy to generate  sequential or  qualitative colour palettes with the number of colours you need. There is also a tool to visualize the palettes. For example:

```
import seaborn as sns

colors = sns.color_palette("hls", 4)
sns.palplot(colors)
plt.savefig("pal1.png")
colors = sns.color_palette("hls", 8)
sns.palplot(colors)
plt.savefig("pal2.png")
colors = sns.color_palette("Set2", 8)
sns.palplot(colors)
plt.savefig("pal3.png")
```

These are the resulting palettes:

[image]

[image]

[image]