# Plotting different colors in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose I have a for loop and I want to plot points in different colors:

```
for i in range(5):
 plt.plot(x,y,col=i)
```

How do I automatically change colors in the for loop?

Comment: IMO [How to get different colored lines for different plots in a single figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805048/how-to-get-different-colored-lines-for-different-plots-in-a-single-figure) is about the color cycle that's restarted in each different `axes` in a `figure`.  There is a possibility I'm wrong...

Answer (score 127):

@tcaswell already answered, but I was in the middle of typing my answer up, so I'll go ahead and post it...

There are a number of different ways you could do this.  To begin with, `matplotlib` will automatically cycle through colors. By default, it cycles through blue, green, red, cyan, magenta, yellow, black:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
for i in range(1, 6):
    plt.plot(x, i * x + i, label='$y = {i}x + {i}$'.format(i=i))
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you want to control which colors matplotlib cycles through, use `ax.set_color_cycle`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_color_cycle(['red', 'black', 'yellow'])
for i in range(1, 6):
    plt.plot(x, i * x + i, label='$y = {i}x + {i}$'.format(i=i))
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you'd like to explicitly specify the colors that will be used, just pass it to the `color` kwarg (html colors names are accepted, as are rgb tuples and hex strings):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
for i, color in enumerate(['red', 'black', 'blue', 'brown', 'green'], start=1):
    plt.plot(x, i * x + i, color=color, label='$y = {i}x + {i}$'.format(i=i))
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Finally, if you'd like to automatically select a specified number of colors from an [existing colormap](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
number = 5
cmap = plt.get_cmap('gnuplot')
colors = [cmap(i) for i in np.linspace(0, 1, number)]

for i, color in enumerate(colors, start=1):
    plt.plot(x, i * x + i, color=color, label='$y = {i}x + {i}$'.format(i=i))
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer is, um, drastically better than mine.

Comment: Thanks!  Yours gets the the main point across in two lines, though. Mine is mostly just being excessively long for the sake of being excessively long...

Comment: downvoted because this is deprecated in P3, to whit "MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The set_color_cycle attribute was deprecated in version 1.5. Use set_prop_cycle instead."

Answer (score 64):

[Joe Kington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/325565/joe-kington)'s [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16006929/2749397) is already 4 years old,
Matplotlib has incrementally changed (in particular, the introduction
of the `cycler` module) and the new major release, Matplotlib 2.0.x,
has introduced stylistic differences that are important from the point
of view of the colors used by default.

#### The color of individual lines

The color of individual lines (as well as the color of different plot
elements, e.g., markers in scatter plots) is controlled by the `color`
keyword argument,

```
plt.plot(x, y, color=my_color)
```

`my_color` is either

- a [tuple of floats](https://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html) representing RGB or RGBA (as`(0.,0.5,0.5)`),
- a [RGB/RGBA hex string](https://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html) (as `"#008080"` (RGB) or `"#008080A0"`),
- a string representation of a float value in [0, 1] inclusive for gray level (e.g., '0.6'),
- a [short color name](https://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html) (as  `"k"` for black, possible values in `"bgrcmykw"`),
- a [long color name](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#svg-color) (as `"teal"`) --- aka *HTML color name* (in [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html) also *X11/CSS4 color name*),
- a [name from the xkcd color survey](https://xkcd.com/color/rgb/), [prefixed with `'xkcd:'`](https://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html) (e.g., `'xkcd:barbie pink'`),
- a [color from the Tableau Colors](https://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html) in the *default* [`'T10'` categorical palette](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/schemes/#category10), (e.g., `'tab:blue'`, `'tab:olive'`),
- a [reference to a color](https://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html) of the *current color cycle* (as `"C3"`, i.e., the letter `"C"` followed by a single digit in `"0-9"`).

#### The *color cycle*

By default, different lines are plotted using different colors, that
are defined by default and are used in a cyclic manner (hence the name
*color cycle*).

The color cycle is a property of the `axes` object, and in older
releases was simply a sequence of valid color names (by default a
string of one character color names, `"bgrcmyk"`) and you could set it
as in

```
my_ax.set_color_cycle(['kbkykrkg'])
```

(as noted [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006572/plotting-different-colors-in-matplotlib#comment74786762_16006929) this API has been deprecated, more on this later).

In Matplotlib 2.0 the default color cycle is `["#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e", "#2ca02c", "#d62728", "#9467bd", "#8c564b", "#e377c2", "#7f7f7f", "#bcbd22", "#17becf"]`, the [Vega category10 palette](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/schemes/#category10).

[image]

<sub>(the image is a screenshot from https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/schemes/)</sub>

E.g.,

```
for i in range(12):plt.plot((0,1),(i/12,i/6),lw=8) # last 2 colors are repeated
```

[image]

#### The *cycler* module: composable cycles

The following code shows that the color cycle notion has been deprecated

```
In [1]: from matplotlib import rc_params

In [2]: rc_params()['axes.color_cycle']
/home/boffi/lib/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py:938: UserWarning: axes.color_cycle is deprecated and replaced with axes.prop_cycle; please use the latter.
  warnings.warn(self.msg_depr % (key, alt_key))
Out[2]: 
['#1f77b4', '#ff7f0e', '#2ca02c', '#d62728', '#9467bd',
 '#8c564b', '#e377c2', '#7f7f7f', '#bcbd22', '#17becf']
```

Now the relevant property is the `'axes.prop_cycle'`

```
In [3]: rc_params()['axes.prop_cycle']
Out[3]: cycler('color', ['#1f77b4', '#ff7f0e', '#2ca02c', '#d62728', '#9467bd', '#8c564b', '#e377c2', '#7f7f7f', '#bcbd22', '#17becf'])
```

Previously, the `color_cycle` was a generic sequence of valid color
denominations, now by default it is a `cycler` object containing a
label (`'color'`) and a sequence of valid color denominations.  The
step forward with respect to the previous interface is that it is
possible to cycle not only on the color of lines but also on other
line attributes, e.g.,

```
In [5]: from cycler import cycler

In [6]: new_prop_cycle = cycler('color', ['k', 'r']) * cycler('linewidth', [1., 1.5, 2.])

In [7]: for kwargs in new_prop_cycle: print(kwargs)
{'color': 'k', 'linewidth': 1.0}
{'color': 'k', 'linewidth': 1.5}
{'color': 'k', 'linewidth': 2.0}
{'color': 'r', 'linewidth': 1.0}
{'color': 'r', 'linewidth': 1.5}
{'color': 'r', 'linewidth': 2.0}
```

As you have seen, the `cycler` objects are *composable* and when you iterate on a composed `cycler` what you get, at each iteration, is a dictionary of keyword arguments for `plt.plot`.

You can use the new defaults on a per `axes` object ratio,

```
my_ax.set_prop_cycle(new_prop_cycle)
```

or you can install temporarily the new default

```
plt.rc('axes', prop_cycle=new_prop_cycle)
```

or change altogether the default editing your `.matplotlibrc` file.

Last possibility, use a context manager

```
with plt.rc_context({'axes.prop_cycle': new_prop_cycle}):
    ...
```

to have the new `cycler` used in a group of different plots, reverting to defaults at the end of the context.

The doc string of the `cycler()` function is useful, but the (not so much) gory details about the `cycler` module and the `cycler()` function, as well as examples, can be found [in the fine docs](https://matplotlib.org/cycler/).

Comment: TL;DR: `plt.gca().set_prop_cycle('color', color_list)`. Great answer, btw!

Answer (score 33):

```
for color in ['r', 'b', 'g', 'k', 'm']:
    plot(x, y, color=color)
```

Comment: If you got a counter handy, you can also do this: `plot(x, y, color="rbgkm"[i])`.