# Python plot time series and emphasize part of it

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, matplotlib

I would like to plot some time series of some data (x axis as time, y axis as some arbitrary data) in Python 2.7.

I need some part of the plot in another color\thicker line\vertical border to emphasize that this is the part of the plot that I want people to pay attention to.

I used matplotlib for the plot and I will be happy to keep working with it, but other ideas good too.

I tried this [draw with matplotlib](https://blog.mafr.de/2012/03/11/time-series-data-with-matplotlib/) but this only tells me how to plot in general i tried this [colors in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006572/plotting-different-colors-in-matplotlib) but this allowed to give different colors to different graph lines and i need to emphasize a part of the same line (a part of the dataset)

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to plot the highlighted section a second time as follows:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

x = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
y = [1.2, 1.5, 2.1, 5.7, 8.3, 10.5, 8.5, 7.3, 9.0, 15.3]

bold = slice(3, 6)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.set_xlabel('Time')
ax.set_ylabel('Data')
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), size=8)
ax.plot(x, y, 'b-', linewidth=2)
ax.plot(x[bold], y[bold], 'y-', linewidth=5)
ax.scatter(x, y)
ax.scatter(x[bold], y[bold], edgecolors='y', linewidths=5)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

This would give you:

[image: Matplot lib screenshot]