# Matplotlib's equivalent of Matlab's hsv(m)

Tags: matplotlib, colors

I have points in `R` clusters. I want create a figure, iterate these `R` clusters and in each iteration `i`, draw points (`scatter`) from cluster `i` with color, that'll be *perceptually* different from colors of points in other clusters.

In Octave/Matlab, I'd just do

```
colors = hsv(R);
figure; hold on;
for i = 1:R
    ...
    c = colors(i,:);
    % draw with color c
    ...
end
```

and each line/set of points would be easily distinguishable from others in the resulting figure. I'm missing this magical [`hsv(n)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hsv.html) function in Matplotlib. I was surprised that I couldn't google it in less than 5 minutes for Matplotlib so hopefully, it'll serve as a reference for other lazy ones.

EDIT:

@ImportanceOfBeingErnest is correct. Also, Matplotlib, unlike Matlab, assigns different color for each plot operation:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16006929/214720

Comment: I could [google it](http://www.google.de/search?q=matplotlib+hsv+colormap) in less then a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hsv colormap in matplotlib is named (oh wonder) `hsv`. For a reference of all colormaps see [Colormap reference](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html).

Note that colormaps in matplotlib range between 0 and 1. Hence, you may need to normalize the input for applying a colormap.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

R = np.linspace(0,1)
color=plt.cm.hsv(R)
```

or

```
R = np.linspace(-3,42)
norm= plt.Normalize(-3,42)
color=plt.cm.hsv(norm(R))
```