# How could I get a different pie chart color

Tags: python, matplotlib

How could I get a different pie chart color? I have a data set about 20 categories and it could be even larger. When I create a pie chart, some wedge have same color, so I wonder is there a way that I can have all colors different in my pie charts' wedge?
Thanks!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4805048/8881141) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16006572/8881141) answer your question? The cmap option is probably the best way for an unknown n although the colors might become quite similar with a high n number.

Comment: Does [this](https://matplotlib.org/1.5.0/examples/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_demo_features.html) answer your question?
Please check out the `color=[colorlist]` option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

20 Colors is exactly the limits of what you can achieve through categorical/qualitative colormaps in matplotlib. Currently matplotlib provides the `tab20`, `tab20b`, `tab20c` colormaps.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(50,200, size=20)

fig = plt.figure()

with plt.style.context({"axes.prop_cycle" : plt.cycler("color", plt.cm.tab20.colors)}):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(121, aspect="equal")
    ax.pie(data)

with plt.style.context({"axes.prop_cycle" : plt.cycler("color", plt.cm.tab20c.colors)}):
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, aspect="equal")
    ax2.pie(data)

plt.show()
```

[image]

For more colors one can of course also use [different colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html), but those will generally result in pretty similar colors next to each other. E.g. for a pie chart with 30 different colors we may use the `nipy_spectral` or the `CMRmap` colormap.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(50,200, size=30)

fig = plt.figure()

cc = plt.cycler("color", plt.cm.nipy_spectral(np.linspace(0,.9,len(data))))
with plt.style.context({"axes.prop_cycle" : cc}):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(121, aspect="equal")
    ax.pie(data)

cc = plt.cycler("color", plt.cm.CMRmap(np.linspace(0,0.9,len(data))))
with plt.style.context({"axes.prop_cycle" : cc}):
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, aspect="equal")
    ax2.pie(data)

plt.show()
```

[image]

So one may add another dimension. Choosing some colors from any colormap and creating different luminosity levels for each of them. This is essentially shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47232942/4124317). Here, in order to get e.g. 30 different colors we may choose 6 colors and for each 5 luminosity levels.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors

def categorical_cmap(nc, nsc, cmap="tab10", continuous=False):
    if nc > plt.get_cmap(cmap).N:
        raise ValueError("Too many categories for colormap.")
    if continuous:
        ccolors = plt.get_cmap(cmap)(np.linspace(0,1,nc))
    else:
        ccolors = plt.get_cmap(cmap)(np.arange(nc, dtype=int))
    cols = np.zeros((nc*nsc, 3))
    for i, c in enumerate(ccolors):
        chsv = matplotlib.colors.rgb_to_hsv(c[:3])
        arhsv = np.tile(chsv,nsc).reshape(nsc,3)
        arhsv[:,1] = np.linspace(chsv[1],0.25,nsc)
        arhsv[:,2] = np.linspace(chsv[2],1,nsc)
        rgb = matplotlib.colors.hsv_to_rgb(arhsv)
        cols[i*nsc:(i+1)*nsc,:] = rgb       
    cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(cols)
    return cmap

data = np.random.randint(50,200, size=30)

fig = plt.figure()

cc = plt.cycler("color", categorical_cmap(6, 5, cmap="tab10").colors)
with plt.style.context({"axes.prop_cycle" : cc}):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(121, aspect="equal")
    ax.pie(data)

cc = plt.cycler("color", 
                categorical_cmap(6, 5, cmap="gist_rainbow", continuous=True).colors)
with plt.style.context({"axes.prop_cycle" : cc}):
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, aspect="equal")
    ax2.pie(data)

plt.show()
```

[image]