# Plotting 2 graphs in 1 window (python)

Tags: python, time, graph, plot

How can I plot two lines in the same plot? The code below is my attempt to do that but it didn't work. 'Temp' is the new variable I added

```
     (2nd EDITED )

    from datetime import datetime
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.dates as mdates
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.stats import mode
    import re
    linematchregex = re.compile('(\d+/\d+/\d+ \d+:\d+),(\d+\.\d+),(\d+\.\d+)')

    startTime = datetime.strptime(raw_input('please enter start time in format like 21/7/2014 0:00 :'), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
    endTime   = datetime.strptime(raw_input('please enter end time in format like 22/7/2014 23:57 :') , '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')

    with open(r'data.txt', 'r') as strm:
        strm.next() #skip first line
        t, y, temp = zip(*[p for line in strm for p in linematchregex.findall(line)])
    t = [datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M') for x in t ]
    temp = [float(x) for i,x in enumerate(temp) if startTime<=t[i]<=endTime]
    y = [float(x) for i,x in enumerate(y) if startTime<=t[i]<=endTime]

    t = [x for x in t if startTime<=x<=endTime]
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, axisbg='white')
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
    ax1.plot(t, y, 'c', linewidth=3.3)
    ax1.plot(t, temp)
    plt.show()
```

My Program can plot TimeStamp with Irradiance but how can i plot all the columns below
Time with Irradiance 
&
Time with Temperature

```
(EDITED)

TimeStamp,Irradiance,Ambient_Temperature
21/7/2014 12:00:06 AM,0.66,29.16
21/7/2014 12:00:20 AM,0.71,29.16
21/7/2014 12:00:34 AM,0.65,29.17
21/7/2014 12:00:48 AM,0.67,29.17
21/7/2014 12:01:08 AM,0.58,29.17
21/7/2014 12:01:23 AM,0.54,29.18
21/7/2014 12:01:37 AM,0.63,29.17
21/7/2014 12:01:52 AM,0.65,29.16
21/7/2014 12:02:07 AM,0.64,29.16
21/7/2014 12:02:22 AM,0.63,29.18
21/7/2014 12:02:36 AM,0.63,29.16
21/7/2014 12:02:50 AM,0.64,29.17
21/7/2014 12:03:04 AM,0.62,29.19
21/7/2014 12:03:24 AM,0.64,29.21
```

Comment: I added a side by side plot answer.  Were you looking to have the datasets plotted on the same graph?

Comment: ya to plot both irradiance,temperature with time on the graph - so like two graphs on the window

Comment: hi Gabriel, thanks for the help, i say wrong - i meant like one graph but with 2 lines

Comment: in that case, just update your definition of `temp` as in my answer and don't do the top part.  if this helps with your problem, please accept the answer by clicking the green arrow next to it.

Comment: when i add the following code, it shows two separate graph, i want to like show one graph but with like 2 lines in it

Comment: ok, Gabriel, what i want is like Irradiance one line then Temperature another line something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805048/how-to-get-different-lines-for-different-plots-in-a-single-figure

Comment: got it.  don't use the top part of my answer.  only change the one line `temp = [float(x) for i,x in enumerate(temp) if startTime<=t[i]<=endTime]` from your original code

Comment: so by changing that it will work?

Comment: the problem wasn't in your plotting it was probably a copy/paste mistake. you had `enumerate(y)` when defining `temp`.  you were getting two line originally, they were just the same line

Comment: but when i run, it only show one line

Comment: what do you get when you print `temp` and print `y`

Comment: how do i print the temp and y

Comment: you left out `ax1.plot(t, temp)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create another subplot in your plot.  Try this,

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1, axisbg='white')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2, axisbg='white')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))
ax1.plot(t, y, 'c', linewidth=3.3)
ax2.plot(t, temp)
```

The method `add_subplot` adds a subplot.  The first two arguments give the number of rows and columns, the third indicates which subplot in the 1x2 matrix you want to create.  The above code will make one subplot on the left and one on the right.  If you want one on top of the other you can reverse the first two arguments in both calls to `add_subplot`.

Another concern is (as best I can tell) there is a bug when you create `temp`,

```
temp = [float(x) for i,x in enumerate(y) if startTime<=t[i]<=endTime]
```

should be

```
temp = [float(x) for i,x in enumerate(temp) if startTime<=t[i]<=endTime]
```

If you want the two plots on the same set of axes your original code will work with just the above change.  If you want the lines to be labelled in a legend you can do that too by changing your plot commands to,

```
ax1.plot(t, y, 'c', linewidth=3.3, label="Irradiance")
ax1.plot(t, temp, label="Temperature")
plt.legend()
```