# Get seperate plots and one accumulated in matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

As to expect I get 2 different plots from the code below. Besides those two I would also like to have one seperate plot that shows both lines in the same graph, with different colours and legend.

I do not want them as sublots, I want each of them as a single plot and one with all the lines in the same plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

for i in range(2):

    x = np.arange(0, 4*np.pi, 0.1)
    y = np.sin(x)

    plt.plot(x, i*y+i)
    plt.title("Values")
    plt.xlabel("x")
    plt.ylabel("y")
    plt.show()
```

I had a look at this stack exchange [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805048/how-to-get-different-colored-lines-for-different-plots-in-a-single-figure/4805456#4805456).

I could write x and y values of each graph to a list to save for later, but for large dataset that does not seem clever.

Comment: Try to *dedent* `plt.show()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which IDE you're using, but your code technically doesn't create two figures. If you only call `plt.plot`, it will create a figure if none exist or add to the last figure if one does exist. You would need to call `plt.figure` if you want to create a new figure.

So, for your case, you want to create a main figure for the combined plots and then create a new figure each loop for the individual plots. The figures can be created using [`plt.subplots()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) (without any `nrows` or `ncols` arguments it creates a single plot, not a matrix of plots).

In the loop I chose to create `fig_i` and `ax_i` for the individual plots and `fig` and `ax` for the global plots. Since you want a legend, you should add a label for the combined plot.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.close("all")

# figure for the combined plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")
ax.set_title("Combined Plot")

x = np.arange(0, 4*np.pi, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x)

for i in range(2):
    # creates a new figure each loop
    fig_i, ax_i = plt.subplots()
    ax_i.plot(x, i*y+i)
    ax_i.set_title("Values")
    ax_i.set_xlabel("x")
    ax_i.set_ylabel("y")
    fig_i.show()

    # adds the data to the combine figure with a label for the legend
    ax.plot(x, i*y+i, label=i)

ax.legend()
fig.show()
```

Individual 1:
[image]

Individual 2:
[image]

Combined:
[image]